# Finding Middle point of list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying a simple piece of code and I couldn't get it work to find the middle point in list. Can someone guide me with logic, please. I am a newbie and I tried a few examples on StackOverflow already but it didn't work for me.

Here is the code:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
midpoint= len(lst)/2
for val in lst[:midpoint]:
     print(val)
```

Error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-452ff692c8fd> in <module>
----> 1 comp(lst)

<ipython-input-66-a6223c2e7902> in comp(lst)
      3 
      4     midpoint= len(lst)/2
----> 5     for val in lst[:midpoint]:
      6         print (val)

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

​
```

Comment: What does `print(middle)` output? `2.0`?

Comment: Tried that before posting the question.

Comment: Since in Python 3.X division operation returns a float value so in your problem, middle will  be 2.0 and list slicing accepts only integer values, so you can cast middle to int and it will work. Same code will work in python 2.X without any change.

Comment: @ZameerAhmed, so what was the output? It'll be `2.0` in Python 3.x. Now, does it make sense to slice a list using a floating-point index, like `3.1415926`, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python3 and in Python 3 you need to use '//' instead of '/' like below.

```
midpoint= len(lst)//2
```

Comment: All of the solutions worked posted by others. But yours is simplest and shortest straight to point. Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
midpoint= int(len(lst)/2)
for val in lst[:midpoint]:
     print(val)
```

Try this

Comment: Or `len(lst) // 2` in Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Assuming list contains only numbers.

- If `len(list)` is even then midpoint or median will be float.
- If `len(list)` is odd then median will be integer.

I would recommend using Python `numpy` module that provides `median` function.

```
from numpy import median
first = [1, 2, 3, 4]    # Even number of elements
print(median(first))
# Output 
2.5

second = [1, 2, 3]    # Odd number of elements
print(median(second))
# Output
2
```

For Python >= 3.4 you can use `statistics` module where you can also find `median` function.

Hope this helps.